# GroupBy on inner lists property

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

I have a list in which i have nested lists like following

```
List = Stylist
Inner List = Listerine
Inner List Property = GroupByProperty
```

Now i want to **group** all `Stylist` items , so that i get result in which i have all records grouped by `GroupByProperty`.

so that i can get all records sorted by `GroupByProperty`

I tried like following

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty == 3).ToList();
```

Comment: *I tried like following* **but**...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or.. If you just want the selection to use WHERE and ORDERBY

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).Where(c => c.GroupByProperty == 3).Orderby(c => c.GroupByProperty).ToList();
```

Or maybe you just want to remove typo Stylist iso Sytlist

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty == 3).ToList();
```

So without the grouping:

```
Stylist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).OrderBy(c => c.GroupByProperty).ToList();
```

And maybe you want to select also the groupbyproperty in the SelectMany

Answer (score 0):

Having `.GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty == 3)` will produce 2 groups. One with GroupByProperty equal to 3 and one with GroupByProperty not equal to 3. You need to add only the property you are grouping by.

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty).ToList();
```

If `c.GroupByProperty == 3` meant to be a filter then you should use a `Where`:

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).Where(c => c.GroupByProperty == 3).GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty).ToList();
```

Though in that case there would not be a meaning in the GroupBy clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GroupBy` statement is wrong. You will get a list grouped by `true` or `false` values, because the statement `c => c.GroupByProperty == 3` will evaluate as boolean.

Instead, you probably need to use:

```
var result = Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).GroupBy(c => c.GroupByProperty);
```

The above will return an collection of `IGrouping` object, rather than a flat list. You can access each group by enumerating it in a similar fashion:

```
foreach (var group in result) {
    var key = group.Key; // this is a single value of the `GroupByProperty` type.
    foreach (var obj in group) {
        // cycle trough all items which are grouped by the current `key` item
    }
}
```

Basically, the `GroupBy` result is like a map, where the key is any single value of the `GroupByProperty` , and the value is a collection of all matching items. You will not receive groups in the result where there are no matches.

---

In case you only need a flat list sorted by the `GroupByProperty`, then the entire `GroupBy` approach is irrelevant. You can simply use:

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).OrderBy(c => GroupByProperty)
```

or

```
Sytlist.SelectMany(x => x.Listerine).OrderBy(c => GroupByProperty, comparer)
```

where the `comparer` is an `IComparer<T>` implementation, and `T` is the type of the `GroupByProperty`. The comparer would be needed in case `T` is not itself a comparable type, or you require a custom comparison logic.